# Multiple media queries on one item

Tags: html, css, styles, media-queries

Is it possible to have multiple media queries for one item in code?

Let me explain,
I'm trying to have a video background work on multiple devices, so far so good, it works, but when on mobile the majority of the video is cut off, same for tablet. So I have 3 videos, one full screen, one 960 x 540 and another 480 x 270. I want to set up a media query that will allow me to switch between these videos depending on the size of the screen. So far I have:

HTML:

```
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="bgvideo">
              <source src="videos/videohd.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="bgvideo-2">
              <source src="videos/video960x540.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <video autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" class="bgvideo-3">
              <source src="videos/video480x270.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo {
    display: block;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: none;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: block;
  }  
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-3 {
    display: none;
  }  
}
```

I'm assuming there is an easier way to do this than what I am doing - as it doesn't work too well!

Thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simplify a bit your `mediaqueries` like this:

```css
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: block;
  }
  .bgvideo-3 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo {
    display: block;
  }
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 960px) {
  .bgvideo {
    display: none;
  }
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .bgvideo-2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .bgvideo-3 {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I shall give this a go! ^^

Comment: Glad to help. If this help you, make sure that you mark this answer as accepted as soon the time let you :)

Comment: It does help but my smallest video is up in the left corner of my screen, have any ideas? :3

Comment: see my updated answer, I totally forgot about `bgvideo-3` :)